# I have a Table and I would like to move Longitude in the Row to the left

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to move Longitude in my table towards the left and it is not working.  I have tried to add rowspan to the row where longitude and latitude is on but that just messes up the rest of my table.  PLus I also need to fix the table-striped for the Description which changed when I added the Latitude and Longitude to the one row.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
[image]

```
<!--Report Table Start -->
<div class="mb-2">
<div class="results-section">
    <div class="report-wrapper" style="display:none" id="report-section">
        <div class="col-auto">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-light">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="report-header" colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">Report</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Address: </th> 
                        <td id="proposed-address">  </td>   
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Latitude: </th>    
                        <td id="proposed-lat"> </td>    
                        <th> Longitude: </th>   
                        <td id="proposed-lng"> </td>    
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Rank: </th>
                        <td id="proposed-rank"> </td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr>
                        <th> Description: </th>
                        <td id="proposed-description"> </td> 
                    </tr>
                    
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>          
</div>
<!--Report Table End -->

.table-borderless td,
.table-borderless th {
  border: 0;
}

.report-wrapper {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height: 25vh;
    display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3px;
      position: relative;
        width: 60vw;
        }
.report-header {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.report-wrapper table{
    width:100%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
} 
.report-wrapper th, td{
  text-align: left;
  }
```

Comment: It appears you are missing some HTML, can you please post it all

Comment: That was weird it was there but not showing.  I just repasted it thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<th>` tags are only supposed to be inside of `<thead>` sections.
`<td>` tags go inside of `<tr>` sections.
The `<th>` tags that are instead of the `<tr>` tags shold be changed to be `<td>`.
The first row (header) in the table should be a `<thead>` not a `<tr>`.

However; I think what you want to do to fix the last column is to remove the width:100% that is inside of the `.report-wrapper table{}` section

Comment: will that also move over the Logitude toward center.  I think I messed up the tags I will play around with it and let you know how this works.

Comment: If you can create a minimal sample that would help - maybe create a stack snippet - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do
Your example as-is has display:none so it is hidden.

Comment: Thanks I will try to add the code snippet Tuesday